# Best way to pass pointers between functions

Tags: c, pointers, return

I'm playing about with C. Just have a few questions on which is best practice and if I'm doing anything wrong.

I've made a program which seems to work:

```
void main()
{
     char *text;
     text = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
     dosomethingwithtext(text);
     printf("%s\n", text);
}
```

However I've also seen versions like this: (I know it won't print anything meaningful because I haven't added any chars, but imagine I had! )

```
void main()
{
    char *text;
    text = dosomething();
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
char * dosomething()
{
    char *text;
    text = malloc(10 * sizeof(char));
    return text;
}
```

Or if either of these are not optimum, what is the best way. Basically I'm asking the most common/best way to do this.

Comment: Kind of opinion based, but I am sure you will get answers that make a case for both ways.  IMO, both way have their advantages depending on where called.  But in both cases, you have to remember the `free()` statement.

Comment: `void main()` is an invalid signature for `main` and deprecated syntax for any function declarator.

Comment: @Olaf `deprecated syntax for any function declarator`, could you expand?

Comment: @xvan: See 6.11.6 in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

a) In both cases you have failed to deallocate the memory. Calls to malloc must be balanced by a call to free.

b) sizeof(char) is defined as 1 in C, so there is no point calling sizeof(char)

c) It's not `void main()`, it's `int main(void)`, or `int main(int argc, char** args)` - you need to provide a return value.

To answer the actual question, either is fine. Arguably in your second case, you make it harder to manage the memory because you can't put the free() in the same function as the malloc() - your dosomething() returns an allocated block. However, it is very common to end up with programs which allocate in one place and free in another.

Comment: I believe the cast from `void*` is now obsolete.

Comment: for C the cast is not necessary.  For C++ it is required.

Comment: On C it may still throw warnings, so it's better to avoid the noise.

Comment: Casting `void *` to pointer in C is discouraged. It definitively is not required. C is not C++.

Comment: @xvan, a C compiler should never throw a warning for that. Casts are a really, really bad habit. Good C code doesn't contain a  single cast.

Comment: Yup, you're right, `void *` is promoted, didn't knew about that.

Comment: Thanks - long time since I did C on a C compiler. Have corrected the answer

Comment: "I did C on a C compiler" - On which compiler did you compile C then if not a C compiler? If you used a C++ compiler, then it was not C code. Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics - you just encountered one of the differences. Others can be more subtle, thus much worse.

Answer (score -1):

Option 1 has the advantage of allocation and dealloction being made on the same scope, which is (*in a completely opinion based*) easier to track and debug. You can use the return value to report some sort of status.

Option 2 follows a [Creational pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern), which is leak prone on unmanaged memory. The only possible status report is a null pointer. (which may or may not be enough).

Comment: Most non-trivial code does not `free` code in the same scope as it has been allocated. It can be as error-prone to pass the allocated memory.

Comment: But forgetting to allocate  memory is easier to debug on any modern OS. To find a leak you first need to be aware that you have one.

Comment: 1) Please address comments properly, otherwise they might not be seen. Said that: There is more to programming in C than PC-level. And your statement is not true as general as it is. There is no simple answer to that and it strongly depends on the application. Just try writing a non-trivial program with dynamically allocated memory and you might understand.